# Operadores en javascript

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear una condición, que me retorne "true", si "number" es divisible entre 3 y 5 (ambos). intenté hacerlo como se muestra, pero el test me da error.  creo que no es la forma de hacerlo. ayuda por favor.

```
function fizzBuzz(number) {
 if(number%3 == 0 && number%5 == 0) {
  return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código está bien. Solo que te falta devolver falso cuando la condición no se cumple.

Algunas opciones:

```
function fizzBuzz(){
     if (number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0){
         return true
     }
     else {
         return false
     }
}


function fizzBuzz(){
     if (number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0){
         return true
     }
     
     return false
}
```

O como el resultado depende solo de esa única condición:

```
function fizzBuzz(){
    return number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0
}
```